# Creating a trigger function in SQL

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I've been given a task to create a trigger function for this question:

Add an update to the support ticket from a given staff member. If the ticket is closed no more updates should be allowed by either customers or staff members.

Insert an update to a ticket with values: ticketUpdateID = 10050; Message ='Highlight folder for backup and press to trash or right click and choose delete'; TicketID = 1010 ; StaffID=2

All I've managed so far is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_ticket()
RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
```

I would just like to know the layout of what i would have to put next.

Thanks

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The question becomes "How do you want to handle bypassing the update: silently ignore the action or raise an exception"? Postgres provides for both cases. The [trigger  function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html) for an Update DML receives 2 pseudo rows conveniently named old and new (at least by default) which represent the current database row and the "tobe" database row respectively. Somewhere in the table definition you have some column indicating the current status of the some value indicating "closed". Unfortunately you have not defined either so I will just make something up for [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b84c9c125c6830c4aa54fed37e1b18d0) purpose. The following will suppress the any update on a 'closed' ticket. I will leave [Raising an exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) for your research.

```
create or replace 
function update_ticket()
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    if old.status = 'closed' then 
       return null;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$;
```